# In a ClearCase config spec, can I make an include statement use the rules already specified?

Tags: clearcase

I'd like to have a ClearCase config spec that has this:

```
element /path/dut.csp  /main/RELEASE_42
include /path/dut.csp
```

The problem I am encountering is that the include statement will include the version of the dut.csp file that is visible in the view before this config spec was set. It does not take into account the element rule the line before.

Sure I can call `cleartool setcs -current`, but what if this sort of approach is used again in the included csp file? How many times do I have to do this before the view is stable?

At the moment I am specifying `@@/main/RELEASE_42` on the include statement as well. But then I have to edit both lines when I change the version. Also, if I want to checkout the csp file for development I then also have to edit my config spec to use the checked-out version.

Is it possible to use the include statement without a revision specification and have the earlier rules in the config spec evaluated before the include statement?

I am using ClearCase version 8.0.0.7.

Comment: I've seen the same issue in our projects. The enlightened minds made all users maintain a file with the config spec in some location. Then, they made a little script that calls `ct setcs <path/to/user/cs>` multiple times. 2 or 3 layers of hierarchy are common. I think to be 100% sure that everything  got set you'd need to do the `setcs` once per each level of include you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't seem possible,  considering the way selection rules are evaluated in a config spec.

That means you need to use:

- a dedicated view to select the right version of that file
- another view to use that include referring the file of the first view